# Dynamic array of structures

Tags: c, structure, dynamic-programming

I'm a beginner and working with DMA and structure of arrays concept coding to get employee's details like name, address, Employee ID, and their age in structure using an array and arranging the received details in ascending order. Here I am not able to figure out the problem with storing the scanned name in the structure. When I give more than two as a value for employees count, then the output of the name is some garbage value. Please help me to fix it. The name that we are entering must be shown but it's not shown up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct emp_details
{
    char *address;
    char *name;
    char *Emp_ID;
    int age;
};

void ascen_str(struct emp_details* employees_data,int num_of_emp);

int main()
{
    int num_of_emp;
    printf("Enter the number of employees: ");
    scanf("%d",&num_of_emp);
    struct emp_details* employees_data = malloc(num_of_emp*sizeof (employees_data));
    int i=0;
    for(int i=0;i<num_of_emp;i++)
    {
        employees_data[i].name=(char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
        printf("Employe %d enter the Name: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",employees_data[i].name);
        printf("%s",employees_data[i].name);
        getchar();
        //sscanf(emp_name,"%s\n",employees_data[i].name);
        //fgets(employees_data[i].name,30,stdin);
        employees_data[i].address = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
        printf("Employe %d enter the Address: ",i+1);
        //scanf("%s",employees_data[i].address);
        fgets(employees_data[i].address,30,stdin);
        employees_data[i].Emp_ID=(char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
        printf("Employe %d enter the Employe ID: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",employees_data[i].Emp_ID);
        printf("Employe %d enter the Age: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&employees_data[i].age);
      
    }
    printf("\n\tEmploye details before sorting\n");
    for(int i=0;i<num_of_emp;i++)
    {    
        printf("Employe %d Name: %s\n",i+1,employees_data[i].name);  
        printf("Employe %d Address: %s",i+1,employees_data[i].address);  
        printf("Employe %d Age: %d\n",i+1,employees_data[i].age);
        printf("Employe %d ID: %s\n\n",i+1,employees_data[i].Emp_ID);
    }   
    ascen_str(employees_data,num_of_emp);
    free(employees_data);
}

void ascen_str(struct emp_details* employees_data, int num_of_emp)
{
    struct emp_details temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_emp; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < num_of_emp; j++) {
            if (strcmp(employees_data[i].name, employees_data[j].name) > 0) {
                temp = employees_data[i];
                employees_data[i] = employees_data[j];
                employees_data[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\tEmploye details in ascending order by name\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_emp; i++) 
    {
        printf("Employe Name: %s\n",employees_data[i].name);  
        printf("Employe Address: %s",employees_data[i].address);  
        printf("Employe Age: %d\n",employees_data[i].age);
        printf("Employe ID: %s\n\n",employees_data[i].Emp_ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of e.g. `employees_data[i].name = malloc(30*sizeof(char))`, why don't you make `name` an array? Like `char name[30];`? The less pointers and the less dynamic allocations you do in your programs, the simpler it will become. And the simpler your program is, the less chances of mistakes.

Comment: And unless your assignment is to make the sorting yourself, then please use [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) instead.

Comment: The garbage value I'm getting is because of the overflow ?

Comment: I want an array of structure to handle those things, so I declared `malloc(num_of_emp*sizeof (employees_data))` using this. Can you tell me any other alternative for this ? @SupportUkraine

Comment: `employees_data` is a *pointer*. The size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself. So `sizeof(employees_data)` will be either `4` or `8` (depending on if you're on a 32 or 64 but system). Much smaller than your actual structure. Use `sizeof *employees_data` instead.

Comment: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof (employees_data));` = 8
 but this is   `printf("%zu\n", sizeof (struct emp_details));` = 32

Comment: `struct emp_details* employees_data = malloc(num_of_emp*sizeof (struct emp_details));` will this do now ?

Comment: Okay okay.. Thank you it's working.
I learnt now to address the memory of the dynamic array thanks for your teaching @SupportUkraine

Comment: Mixing `scanf()` with `fgets()` is a worry. `scanf()` will leave whitespace in the input buffer, and the subsequent `fgets()` will likely "sweep up" an empty line because LF is a whitespace character... Don't mix and match... Go with `fgets()` consistently... Do all employees have only one name? `scanf()` will return "Bob" for "Bob Jones", leaving " Jones" in the buffer for the next suck on the pipe...

Comment: Understood and made changes @Fe2O3

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why don't you post the answer as THE answer and not just in comment ? It would be nice for other people here trying to help to see at first sight that there's already an good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct emp_details* employees_data = malloc(num_of_emp*sizeof (employees_data));
```

replace this statement by

```
struct emp_details* employees_data = malloc(num_of_emp*sizeof (struct emp_details ));
```

Because `employees_data` is a pointer and it's size is not the structure size

Answer (score 2):

**Allocate to the size of the referenced object, not the size of the pointer**
[@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74938077/dynamic-array-of-structures/74938719#comment132243448_74938077)

```
// struct emp_details* employees_data = malloc(num_of_emp*sizeof (employees_data));
struct emp_details* employees_data = malloc(num_of_emp * sizeof employees_data[0]);
```

When able, avoid sizing/casting to the *type* and allocate to the referenced object, as below.  It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof prt[0] * number_of_elements);
```

**Avoid `fgets()` with `scanf()`**  [@Fe2O3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74938077/dynamic-array-of-structures/74938719#comment132243631_74938077)

How about just `fgets()`?  Create 2 helper functions.

```
// Minimal error checking
int get_int() {
  char buf[1000];
  if (fget(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }
  int val;
  if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &val) == 1) {
    return val;
  }
  return 0;
}  

// Allocate the string size based on length of input.
// Minimal error checking
char *get_string() {
  char buf[1000];
  if (fget(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  size_t len = strlen(buf);
  if (len > 0 && buf[len-1] == 0) {
    buf[--len] = 0; // lop off potential \n
  }
  char *s = malloc(len + 1);
  if (s) {
    strcpy(s, buf);
  }
  return s;
}
```

We can improve these helper functions later to detect lengthy input, `int` overflow, end-of-file, ...

**Simplify record reading**

```
 // Error checking omitted for brevity.
for(int i=0; i < num_of_emp; i++) {
    printf("Employe %d enter the Name: ",i+1);
    employees_data[i].name = get_string();

    printf("Employe %d enter the Address: ",i+1);
    employees_data[i].address = get_string();

    printf("Employe %d enter the Employe ID: ",i+1);
    employees_data[i].Emp_ID = get_string();

    printf("Employe %d enter the Age: ",i+1);
    employees_data[i].age = get_int();
  }
}
```